# git: How to do a merge so only "branch-local" commits are merged?

Tags: git, merge

Say I have branches `A`, `B`, and `C`. `A` has been merged into `B` in the past. Now I want to merge `B` into `C`, such that it brings in only commits specific to `B`, and not any of the changes that were merged in from `A`.

**Updated to add**: I'd like to be able to use a single command/"operation" to do this. Something like `git merge --native-only` :)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to [cherry pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the specific commits you applied to B.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- but I'd like to be able to use a single command/"operation" to do this (and I should have mentioned this in the question). Something like "git merge --native-only" :)

Comment: How is Git supposed to you what you in this particular case consider "native"?